# swift: Update parse object without knowing his objectId

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

i have a userSignUp and login System where a user is stored with his email address and password.

Later i want to add more information to this user, so i created a new data class on parse.com with the name "UserProfile" where i store the userObjectId from the user that has been signed up.

So now i want to update this user in the data class UserProfile but i just now the objectId from the user in the UserClass.
So i want to update like "update user where userObjectId = PFUser.currentUser().objectId"

i have this snippet of code already:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"UserProfiles")
    var userId = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId?
    query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: userId)
    //i don't think, that the following code is correct
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") {
        (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else if let gameScore = gameScore {
            gameScore["cheatMode"] = true
            gameScore["score"] = 1338
            gameScore.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "userObjectId" field is a string field and not a pointer field, then you can do this.

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "UserProfiles")
var userId = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId

query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: userId)
//here you would just find the results
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        //you have the user, assuming one but their could be more
        //this will only return one user since you're using the objectID as a field and those are unique, so...

        for user in objects! {
            user["aColumnYouWishToUpdate"] = whatYouWishToUpdateTo
            user["anotherColumnToUpdate"] = anotherUpdatedVariable
            //do this for any columns you want updated
            user.saveInBackground() //to save the newly updated user
        } 

    } else {
        //you have an error
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.

so it would look like this?

var query = PFQuery(className: "UserProfiles")
var userId = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId

query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: userId)
//here you would just find the results
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        query["name"] = "new Name"
        query.saveInBackground()  

    } else {
        //you have an error
    }
}

Comment: What are you trying to do once you receive the objects from the "UserProfiles" class?

Comment: in mysql it would look like query("UPDATE UserProfiles SET name = "New Name" WHERE UserObjectId = $user"); - i hope you can understand?!

Comment: i want to add cols and / or update rows for ONE special user with the unique userObjectId PFUser.currentUser().objectId

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully try and help you out.

Comment: Thank you. It is now telling me that Type PFObject does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType' in the line of the for loop

Comment: with "in objects!" i get "Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'AnyObject?!' for user["aColumnYouWishToUpdate"] = whatYouWishToUpdateTo

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Yes, I get that, but what are you trying to accomlish with the code? It's hard for me to help you when my answer is just generic, and you don't provide me with anything specific.

Comment: i have a database named User und an other named UserProfiles. In User i have all my users with email address and password and objectId (unique primary key) - in UserProfiles i want to store more data of a user so I create an row with a col called "UserObjectId" where I save the objectId from the database User. Now in the "UserProfileViewController" the user can update his profile und when he is saving is, i want to update the row in UserProfiles with his new data